# vim-airline customization: parse substring from current branch name

Tags: vimscript, plugin-airline

We're formatting our branch name like `feature/HD-1234_tiny_description` where "1234" refers to a Jira ticket number. I'd like to only display this number in vim-airline (along with vim-fugitive)

According to the docs:

> vim-airline will display the branch-indicator together with the branch name
> in the statusline, if one of the following plugins is installed:
>
> - fugitive.vim https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive
> - ...
>
> if a string is provided, it should be the name of a function that
> takes a string and returns the desired value
>
> ```
> let g:airline#extensions#branch#format = 'CustomBranchName'
> function! CustomBranchName(name)
>     return '[' . a:name . ']'
> endfunctionlet
> ```

So I'm naively tried

```
let g:airline#extensions#branch#format = 'JiraTicketNumber'
function! JiraTicketNumber(name)
  return matchstr(name, '/feature\/hd[-_]{1}(\d{4})/i')[1]
endfunction
```

which returns an error `undefined variable : name` (roughly translated).

Could anyone give me an helping hand ?

---

Ideally I'd like to return the ticket number only if the branch name starts by "feature" (so `fix/...` and `chore/...` would be simply truncated via `let g:airline#extensions#branch#format = 1`)

Should this work ?

```
let g:airline#extensions#branch#format = 'JiraTicketNumber'
function! JiraTicketNumber(name)
  if name =~ 'feature'
    return matchstr(name, '/feature\/hd[-_]{1}(\d{4})/i')[1]
  else
    return name
  endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that in the example they use `a:name` to refer to the argument; in VimScript prior to `vim9script` you must prefix arguments with `a:` because you reference them in the "argument namespace" (actually a dictionary).

Try (where I've also touched up the pattern, the `=~[#]` operator, and used the `matchlist` function)

```
let g:airline#extensions#branch#format = 'JiraTicketNumber'
function JiraTicketNumber(name) abort
  if a:name =~# 'feature'
    return matchlist(a:name, 'feature\/HD[-_]\(\d\{4}\)')[1]
  else
    return a:name
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: It works like a charm ! I'll have a closer look at what you touched up. Thanks for the introduction to vimscript :)